# Связь между удалённым репозиторием и локальным

Tags: git, github

Есть репозиторий на GitHub и на локальном компьютере, они связаны.

Я переименовал репозиторий на GitHub и на локальном компьютере.

Как их связать заново, чтобы можно было дальше работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на самом деле эти хранилища **абсолютно** независимы и **самодостаточны**.

но для удобства обмена информацией удобно обозначить какое-нибудь хранилище (или несколько) условным именем. посомтреть такие обозначения:

```
$ git remote show
origin
```

посмотреть url хранилища с коротким именем `origin` можно, например, так:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url 
https://github.com/ticky/sepulka
```

установить другой url можно, например, так:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url новый-url
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Всё получилось.
Единственное при попытке запушить изменения возникает следующая ошибка
http://joxi.ru/GrqZBxPHNvqj9m

Comment: [git+permission+denied+publickey](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=git+permission+denied+publickey)

Comment: Благодарю за наводку.