# Почему не могу сделать pull на серевере?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Меня подключили к удаленному репозиторию. Захожу на сервер через `ssh`. Делаю `git pull.`
вот так получаю

```
git pull
Password for 'https://skavorodka@bitbucket.org': // ввожу свой пароль от gita и получаю
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://skavorodka@bitbucket.org/skavorodka/rtiger.git/'
```

ключ `ssh` есть. Что не так ?

Comment: Введите правильный пароль.

Comment: `Что не так ?` - `Invalid username or password`

Comment: Пароль должен быть от пользователя `skavorodka` , но не в коем случае от другого пользователя git. Тут явно указано что выполняете действия от пользователя git skavorodka@

Comment: @MrFylypenko тоесть мой проль не смотря на то что я присоединен к репозиторию не подходит ?

Comment: @Sergalas совершенно верно. Вы же вводите пароль не от  `skavorodka` , поэтому и не пустит в гит. Если из url уберете `skavorodka@` то гит сначала попросит ввести имя пользователя и пароль, а не только пароль.

Comment: @MrFylypenko и это действует для сайта ? То есть если я на сайте (не смотря на то что у меня есть доступ к репозиторию меня присоединили). И указано все то что указали вы то получается ошибка ?

Comment: @Sergalas если вы попытаетесь скопировать ссылку на репозиторий (сделать clone), то она по умолчанию будет выглядеть: `https://<YOUR_LOGIN>@bitbucket.org/skavorodka/rtiger.git/` , т.е. с указанием конкретного логина, под которым вы находитесь на сайте. И в дальнейшем используется как автоподстановка этого логина. Такое поведение bitbucket по умолчанию, но можно и убирать `<YOUR_LOGIN>@` , тогда при pull будет спрашивать и логин и пароль.

Answer (score 2):

#### немного теории

[общий синтаксис uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax):

```
URI = scheme:[//authority]path[?query][#fragment]
```

где компонент `authority` делится на три части:

```
authority = [userinfo@]host[:port]
```

а компонент `userinfo`, в свою очередь, может содержать имя пользователя и (опционально) пароль:

```
userinfo = user[:password]
```

#### практика

вы указали в качестве *uri* строку:

```
https://skavorodka@bitbucket.org
```

т.е., собираетесь аутентифицироваться на сервере `bitbucket.org` с именем пользователя `skavorodka` и (запрашиваемым интерактивно) паролем, который явно принадлежит **другой** учётной записи.

следовательно, вам надо либо указать именно ту учётную запись, от которой у вас имеется пароль:

```
https://ваша-учётная-запись@bitbucket.org
```

можно даже сразу с паролем:

```
https://ваша-учётная-запись:пароль@bitbucket.org
```

либо вообще не указывать (тогда она будет запрошена клиентской программой интерактивно):

```
https://bitbucket.org
```

---

полезная информация касательно url хранилища: [Связь между удалённым репозиторием и локальным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/779704/178576)

Comment: я где то писал что я указал. Этот url вываливается  при git pull

Comment: @Sergalas, дополнил ответ.